# How to setup static ip on Ubuntu Server 18.04 in VMWare Workstation 14

Tags: server, 18.04, vmware, static-ip

I am new so please bear with me.

I am on a laptop with Windows 10 (which totally sucks) connected by **wifi**, and trying to **setup a static ip in Ubuntu Server 18.04 in VMWare Workstation 14**.  I have googled how to set this up with a static ip, but none of the directions worked for me.  I have tried over and over, but I must be missing something.  I admit my uderstanding is minimal, however I am trying to learn.

I understand that netplan is the new way as of version 17.  Can anyone help me set this up?  I do know how to view my virtual machine's ip information.  However I cannot seem to configure it properly for the static ip address change.  Is there anything speacial that I need to do outside of what google has?

I reinstalled the distro and used dhcp because I am a novice at configuring such networking settings.  When I give the command: **ip a**     I get this below....

```
root@servertest:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:dd:61:82 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet **192.168.159.134/24** brd 192.168.159.255 scope global dynamic ens33
       valid_lft 1594sec preferred_lft 1594sec
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fedd:6182/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I see that my local ip is "inet 192.168.159.134" is that correct?

How do I take this information and make the changes needed to have a static ip in my virtual machine?

Google gave me a **.yaml file** in **/etc/netplan/** that you must make changes on:

**network:

```
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
        eth0:
              dhcp4: no
              dhcp6: no
              addresses: [192.168.1.70/24]
              gateway4: 192.168.1.1
              nameservers:
                      addresses: [192.168.1.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]**
```

I plugged in my info but my machine lost connection after.  Unless I leave dhcp on, I am stuck.  I am trying to practice hosting my own small websites as training to learn linux administration.  If I can finally get this static ip right, I can move on to LAMP.  If anyone can help a noob out, I'd appreciate it more than you know.  Thanks for reading this long post if you made it this far.  I await your instructions jedi master!....Lol...seriously though.